# Laravel Table Filters

Tags: laravel, filter, eloquent, frameworks

I'm trying to implement filters on a table in my Laravel application. For example, I have an Orders table with a column 'order status'. I want to have a button I can click so that I can see all the delivered orders (apart from the pending orders). The thing I tried is giving me a blank page and a changed URL. This is what I am trying to do.

**View**

```php
<form action="{{ action('FilterController@status_filter') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" name="pending" value="1">Pending</button>
    <button type="submit" name="delivered" value="2">Delivered</button>
</form>

@if(count ($info) > 0)
    <table>
        <thead>
        <th>orderNumber</th>
        <th>orderDate</th>
        <th>shippedDate</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>comments</th>
        <th>customerNumber</th>
        </thead>
        @foreach ($info as $info)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $info->orderNumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ $info->orderDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ $info->shippedDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ $info->status }}</td>
                <td>{{ $info->comments }}</td>
                <td>{{ $info->customerNumber }}</td>
            </tr>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

**Controller**

```php
<?php

public function status_filter(Request $request)
{
    $filter = FilterModel::where('status', true);

    if ($request->has('1')) {
        $filter->where('status', $pending);
    }

    if ($request->has('2')) {
        $filter->where('status', $delivered);
    }

     return $filter->get();

    return redirect('filter', ['filter' => $filter]);

}
```

**Route**

```
 Route::post('status_filter', 'FilterController@status_filter');
```

Model:

```
 class FilterModel extends Model
 {
protected $table = 'orders';
protected $primarykey = 'orderNumber';
 }
```

Table Schema:

[image: Table Schema]

Comment: Laravel 419 post error is usually related with token authorization

Comment: I changed my route to a get and now the error is gone. The only thing that happens right now is that my URL changes.

Comment: Have you tried my change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making a POST request. On every POST request, Laravel checks for CSRF token which it will not find in your POST request because your form is missing CSRF token. Your form is

```
<form action="{{ action('FilterController@status_filter') }}" method="POST">
     <button type="submit" name="pending" value="1">Pending</button>
     <button type="submit" name="delivered" value="2">Delivered</button>
</form>
```

and it should be

```
<form action="{{ action('FilterController@status_filter') }}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     <button type="submit" name="pending" value="1">Pending</button>
     <button type="submit" name="delivered" value="2">Delivered</button>
</form>
```

there are multiple ways to add CSRF token

- {!! csrf_field() !!}
- @csrf
- `<input type="hidden" name="_token" id="csrf-token" value="{{ Session::token() }}" />`

Comment: Thank you, the error is gone. but now the table isn't changing as I want to. It is only showing me a blank page and the URL changed.

Comment: @stefandeboer as you are returning the data from $filter collection and you see a blank page that means that $filter returns an empty array in that case you should at least see brackets and if you don't even see brackets( [ ] ) then please share your table and model.

Comment: i updated my post, so now it shows my table schema and my model.

Comment: @stefandeboer that means your filter returns an empty array. Check your filters. use dd(); method to debug

Comment: @stefandeboer I think issue is in this filter $filter = FilterModel::where('status', true);
If you are storing true as a string in you DB then write it as  $filter = FilterModel::where('status', 'true'); or use whatever real value you have stored in the table.
If you are checking for null then it should be like $filter = FilterModel::whereNotNull('status');

Answer (score 1):

[Post requests are protected by csrf by default](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf). Use `@csrf` to add the csrf token to your form.

```
<form action="{{ action('FilterController@status_filter') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" name="pending" value="1">Pending</button>
    <button type="submit" name="delivered" value="2">Delivered</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only show a blank page because your method return some datas, and not a view.
You need to display a view, or redirect with using redirect method

[See Documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#creating-redirects)

Comment: But regardless if I show my view or not, shouldn't it show the corresponding data then? right now it is not showing any data.

Comment: can you show us your controller updated ? 

you put data into the redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this in your controller

```
public function status_filter(Request $request) {
    $status = $request->status;
    $return FilterModel::where('status', $status)->get();
}
```

and your form

```
<form action="{{ action('FilterController@status_filter') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit" name="status" value="pending">Pending</button>
    <button type="submit" name="status" value="delivered">Delivered</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @Stormhammer, it is finally showing data. But it is not showing the correct data. When I click the Delivered button, the record with the status pending is still showing.

Comment: I modified my answer. I think this should work. If it does, you should also concider adding `$request->validate(['status'=>'required']);` above `$status =.....` in the controller.